# Create Ebay Connector using Syncari SDk

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, sdk

i'm trying to create a connector inside Syncari SDK to get Orders from Ebay using this SDK

https://pypi.org/project/syncari-sdk/

in ebay am using Production environment using **Auth'n'Auth**

[image]

**and with this Token am using:**

```
 1. Trading API 
 2.API CALL : GetOrders
 3.API VERSION : 967
```

[image]

**HTTP headers**

```
X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:967
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GetOrders
```

**Request Body**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <OrderIDArray>
    <!-- Enter one or more of the seller's Order IDs in separate OrderID fields. Only legacy Order IDs are supported in GetOrders and not the ExtendedOrderIDs that are supported in eBay REST APIs calls like the Fulfillment API. The legacy Order ID values are actually the concatenation of ItemID and TransactionID, with a hyphen in between these two values. In legacy API calls, the OrderLineItemID and OrderID values are the same for single line item orders. Note that the TransactionID for an auction listing is always '0', which is demonstrated below -->
    <OrderID>XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX</OrderID>
    <OrderID>XXXXXXXXXXXX-0</OrderID>
  </OrderIDArray>
  <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

Inside SDK we have a method called : synapse_Info() to connect to ebay using token

Read the document here : https://support.syncari.com/hc/en-us/articles/4580013102868-Custom-Synapse-SDK-Documentation

i want to know how to add Headers, Toekn , Body to get Orders From Ebay API and add all of this here

```
def synapse_info(self):
    return SynapseInfo(
    name='lysiSynapse', category='other',
    metadata=UIMetadata(displayName='Lysi Synapse'),
    supportedAuthTypes=[AuthMetadata(authType=AuthType.BASIC_TOKEN, label='API Key', fields=[AuthField(name='token', label='API Key', dataType=DataType.PASSWORD)])],
    configuredFields=[AuthField(name='endpoint', label='Endpoint URL', dataType=DataType.STRING)])
```

we can see response usning Method : Test() in the SDK

```
def test(self, connection: Connection):
 self.client.get("/users",headers=self.__auth_headers())
 if not connection.metaConfig:
     connection.metaConfig={}
 return connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synapse_info info method is meant to be used to declare the Synapse’s UI elements and authentication options and not to add headers and tokens directly. The method returns a SynapseInfo object that defines fields in the Syncari’s UI. It is possible later in the framework to access those defined fields from the connection object, which persist through the framework.

We recommend first is to define the Syncari rest client in the Synapse class:

```
def __init__(self, request: Request) -> None:
    super().__init__(request)
    self.client = SyncariRestClient(self.connection.authConfig.endpoint, self.connection.authConfig)
```

This way it’s possible to use the Syncari client that will have access to the endpoint and authentication data that the user inputs in the UI of Syncari.

Since Ebay's API uses XML queries we’d recommend creating helper methods to assist with constructing the queries. For this particular example:

```
def xmlQueryConstructorGetOrderByID(eBayAuthToken, Orders):
    return f"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><GetOrderRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\"><RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>{eBayAuthToken}</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials><ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage><WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel><OrderIDArray>{Orders}</OrderIDArray><OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole></GetOrderRequest>""
```

Additionally, we recommend to hardcode the required headers in a constant:

```
HEADERS = {"Content-Type":"application/xml", "x-ebay-api-call-name": "GetOrders", "x-ebay-api-compatibility-level" : "967", "X-EBAY-API-SITEID" : "0"}
```

We can now use all of this to make a call in the test method, which is used to test the credentials a user imputed in the UI of Syncari application:

```
def test(self, connection: Connection):
    self.client.get("", headers=HEADERS, data=self.client.post("",headers=HEADERS,
    data=xmlQueryConstructorGetOrderByID(self.connection.authConfig.token,"<OrderID>XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX</OrderID>")))
    return connection
```

In an actual use case the  would be replaced with an actual existing order’s ID and the authentication data is accessed from the connection object.

We also recommend using a python library like xmltodict to convert the received XML data into JSON, so it is easier to pass it to Syncari.

We hope this answers the question but if you need any further assistance please reach out to our support at developers@syncari.com.